# angular.js:9827 POST http://localhost:64340/Content 405 (Method Not Allowed)

Tags: angularjs, html, file-upload

Can any one help me out with this....
I am trying to browse file and want to save into some folder using angular.
Here is my HTML code

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">

    <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <input type="file" file-model="myFile" />
        <button ng-click="uploadFile()">upload me</button>
    </div>
    <script src="app/fileUpload.js"></script>  
</body>
</html>
```

My JS Controller File:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.config([
        '$httpProvider',
        function($httpProvider) {
            $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
        }
]);

myApp.directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
            var modelSetter = model.assign;

            element.bind('change', function () {
                scope.$apply(function () {
                    modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
                });
            });
        }
    };
}]);

myApp.service('fileUpload', ['$http', function ($http) {
    this.uploadFileToUrl = function (file, uploadUrl) {
        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append('file', file);

        $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
            transformRequest: angular.identity,
            headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined }
        })

        .success(function () {
        })

        .error(function () {
        });
    }
}]);

myApp.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', 'fileUpload', function ($scope, fileUpload) {
    $scope.uploadFile = function () {
        var file = $scope.myFile;

        console.log('file is ');
        console.dir(file);

        var uploadUrl = "/Content";

        fileUpload.uploadFileToUrl(file, uploadUrl);
    };
}]);
```

My Web.config File : I have added 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' but still it is not working.
Is there anything I am misssing ?

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>

    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>``
```

Error Pic :

[image: Not Able to Upload file]

Answer (score 0):

> 405 errors often arise with the POST method. You may be trying to introduce some kind of input form on the Web site, but not all ISPs allow the POST method necessary to process the form.

the server needs you to specify a `Content-Type` and/or `Accept` in your request header.

```
$http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
    transformRequest: angular.identity,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
    },
})
```

Comment: ok can you give a try by adding HEAD in `<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD" />`

Comment: Thanks Pratik for your help, but this also didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Much of those are default properties already. Waste of effort adding properties to requests that are already set as default

Comment: Add ContentType  "application/x-www-form-urlencoded".

And Convert your POST data to a serialized "key1=val1&key2=val2" string.

Answer (score 0):

In the server side add this `header` to the response:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
```

If your server using PHP I use this script:

```
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X-Requested-With, X-YOUR-CUSTOM-HEADER');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
```